# return a function without params in coffeescript using do

Tags: coffeescript

I want to use do to call a function without parameters like so:

```
do someMethod
```

from experimenting it seems like I can also write:

```
total = 42
do total.toString
```

question, can I do this:

```
return do next if request.someField == 'ok'
```

instead of:

```
return next() if request.someField == 'ok'
```

Comment: I've tried it and it seems to work :) but i want to make sure it will work as intended

Comment: Also, I'm curious whether there's some kind of convention about this. Method chaining with or without parens seems to be a religious subject in coffeescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

I see you are asking about convention. The convention, AFAIK, is to use parentheses when there are no parameters: `foo()`, and to use do when it's convenient to wrap a few variables in a closure:

```
for item, index in items
  do (item, index) ->
    // Do some stuff
```

Comment: That's a special-case where you can't replace `do` with `()`. Convention doesn't matter there.